# Flask: how to only render_template if a variable exists

Tags: python, flask

I have several variables in Flask. The quantity of variables, depend on how many columns an Excel spreadsheet has.

The problem is that those variables, existing or not, are there in the **render_template**. So, if the Excel spreadsheet has less columns, then some variables are not declared and the render_template fails.

I am going to declare those variables as empty before the re-assignment. But this will give me Null/None, which I will have to work around, post removing them - and it doesn't sound very good when I am willing to make the code as fast as possible.

**Is there any way better than using if conditions in order to avoid "render_template", when a variable doesn't exist? Or even better than pre-assigning them as empty?**

## My code:

```
try: label_a = sheet.cell(0, 0).value
except: pass
try: label_b = sheet.cell(0, 1).value
except: pass
try: label_c = sheet.cell(0, 2).value
except: pass
try: label_d = sheet.cell(0, 3).value
except: pass
try: label_e = sheet.cell(0, 4).value


return render_template('index.html',
    label_a=label_a, label_b=label_b, label_c=label_c, label_d=label_d, label_e=label_e
)
```

Comment: You can easily put the `render_template` call inside an appropriate `if` statement. But it's not clear what you want to happen if the condition fails. It seems likely that you will always want to render the template and should just use appropriate `{% if ... %}` tags in the template to check if the variables exist.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I am trying to avoid if conditions. By now, I am going to pre-assign them as empty (before the re-assignment). But any of those ways will give me difficult time in the future, if the code has to be changed. There are hundreds of variables not expressed here.

Comment: wow, well in that case I don't have enough idea about your actual use case to really make an appropriate recommendation, but passing "hundreds" of different variables to a template seems like a "code smell" in the first place. You might be able to simplify it (eg. by putting all the variables into a dictionary without having to create them all one-by-one), but I'd also want (if i were you) to take a step back and wonder if you really needed all of that information in just one template.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, Thanks for the suggestions. I only render the header(first row) of each existing column in the spreadsheet. And I have to be prepared for the 'worst scenario'. The user selects the headers (I call it labels) he wants to analyse. Then, I pull the data in the column relate to the selected header, instead of rendering them too. Just to clarify: If I have 250 columns in an Excel spreadsheet, I will render 250 words, only :)